# Find oldest files in the directory based on the filename Timestamp in unix

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I want the oldest files in the directory based on the file name date and timestamp to be listed first.

Example:

input file :

```
AAAG11020709581.txt
AAAG13020709581.txt
AACL11020709581.txt
AACL13020709581.txt
AAFU11020709581.txt
AAFU13020709581.txt
AAHO11020709581.txt
AAHO13020709581.txt
AAPC11020709581.txt
AAPC13020709581.txt
AAPO11020709581.txt
AAPO13020709581.txt
AATR11020709581.txt
AATR13020709581.txt
AARC11020709581.txt
AARC13020709581.txt
```

Expected output :

```
AAAG11020709581.txt
AACL11020709581.txt
AAFU11020709581.txt
AAHO11020709581.txt
AAPC11020709581.txt
AAPO11020709581.txt
AARC11020709581.txt
AATR11020709581.txt
AAAG13020709581.txt
AACL13020709581.txt
AAFU13020709581.txt
AAHO13020709581.txt
AAPC13020709581.txt
AAPO13020709581.txt
AARC13020709581.txt
AATR13020709581.txt
```

Can anyone please suggest ?

Comment: Do you want them to be sorted or just print certain ones?

Comment: I want them to be sorted

Comment: Then you can use `sort` command after `ls`.

Comment: it doesn't work, 13 and 11 will come together... as 11 is the oldest date so it should come first, but it is not coming

Comment: AAAG11020709581.txt
AAAG13020709581.txt
AACL11020709581.txt
AACL13020709581.txt
AAFU11020709581.txt
AAFU13020709581.txt
AAHO11020709581.txt
AAHO13020709581.txt
AAPC11020709581.txt
AAPC13020709581.txt
AAPO11020709581.txt
AAPO13020709581.txt
AARC11020709581.txt
AARC13020709581.txt
AATR11020709581.txt
AATR13020709581.txt

Comment: Please update your question with proper explanation and new code. In comments it is very complicated to read code.

Comment: @Pooja: why is your sorted list longer than the unsorted one?

Comment: I had missed few records, updated now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sort will by default sort with the beginning of the line as key. You can tell it to start at a different place with the `-k FIELD.OFFSET` notation, e.g. if all filenames begin with 4 letters, you can skip these like this:

```
sort -k1.5
```

Output:

```
AAAG11020709581.txt
AACL11020709581.txt
AAFU11020709581.txt
AAHO11020709581.txt
AAPC11020709581.txt
AAPO11020709581.txt
AARC11020709581.txt
AATR11020709581.txt
AAAG13020709581.txt
AACL13020709581.txt
AAFU13020709581.txt
AAHO13020709581.txt
AAPC13020709581.txt
AAPO13020709581.txt
AARC13020709581.txt
AATR13020709581.txt
```